# Run MySql.exe as SystemVariable using PowerShellScript

Tags: mysql, powershell, window

I successfully added my mysql path to System Variables in Windows variable Path. If I run cmd and then mysql.exe. It will execute the program without problems.

I want to run mysql.exe from PowerShell

```
$mysql = "mysql.exe"
$params = "-C","-B","-h$server","-P$port","-u$user","-p$password",$db,"-e$query"
&  $mysql @params
```

I tried ./mysql.exe and mysql.exe but it's not working.

I get the error: *The term 'mysql.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.*

Thanks in Advance for your Help.

Comment: If dot sourcing from a working directory is giving you that error, you'll need to either dot source using the full path, add the mysql.exe to your environmental path, or use the "Start-Process" cmdlet (with the full path).

Comment: `.\command` or `./command` is not dot-sourcing. Dot-sourcing is when there is a space after the dot. Run `help about_Scopes` for more details and read the section titled "Using Dot Source Notation with Scopes."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that PowerShell is a shell that can run commands: You put the command at the beginning of the line, and you put the arguments afterward. If any of the arguments come from variables, just put them there. This is all you need to do:

```
mysql.exe -C -B "-h$server" "-P$port" "-u$user" "-p$password" $db "-e$query"
```

For parameters that have their argument "pasted" directly to the parameter (like `-P<port>`), quote the parameter so PowerShell knows to do the variable expansion within the string.

Of course in this example we are assuming that `mysql.exe` is in the `Path`. If it's not and you need to specify the full path and filename to `mysql.exe`, just put the full path and filename of `mysql.exe`:

```
& "C:\Program Files\MySQL\bin\mysql.exe" ...
```

(That path is made up.) The quotes (`"`) are required since the path contains white space, and the `&` tells PowerShell to execute the quoted string as a command (rather than simply interpreting it as a string).

Comment: Thanks it also worked with `$params = "-C","-B","-h$server","-P$port","-u$user","-p$password",$db,"-e$query"
&  mysql @params` @Bill_Stewart

Comment: The commas are not necessary.