# Execute mysql dump using power shell

Tags: mysql, powershell, azure-sql-database

I am setting up a new Azure database using mysql server with a database. I want to dump a .sql file to this database using powershell

Executing the below code throws exception in '<', since it is reserved for future use, as a workaround I tired putting the entire statement in quotes.Still facing same issue.

`$path = "C:\tools\mysql\current\bin\mysql.exe"
&"$path"  -h $servername -u $username -p $databasename  < filename.sql`

The expected result is to dump the filename.sql into mysql server database.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40173988/use-mysql-console-through-a-powershell-script https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46937146/run-mysql-exe-as-systemvariable-using-powershellscript?rq=1

Comment: The above link doesn't explain about importing. I am specifically looking for importing mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this and see if it helps:

Use Get-Content to read the file and pipe | it to your command. Use & to run the command.

```
get-content 'c:\folder\backup.sql' | &"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysql.exe" -u user --password=pass dbnamedbname
```